# After updating a div's content with ajax, card expands upwards instead of downwards

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 grid layout. There is a main container in which the data is being reloaded/updated with Ajax. After container's content is loaded through pagination, at the bottom of the screen and I'm expanding the last card, the expansion goes upwards. After scrolling up and then back down, it goes downwards. This issue only happens in Chrome. I tested on IE/Edge/Firefox and it works as expected.

This is what is happening. Notice the scrollbar on the right.

**Navigating to 2nd page**
[image]
*Clicking expand arrow*

**Expected result:**
[image]
*The card expands downwards and the scroll bar remains in place. The distance from top to itself remains the same.*

**Actual result:**
[image]
*It feels like the card is collapsing upwards. The scroll bar remains at the bottom and the distance from top to itself increases, as if the scroll bar got stuck to the bottom.*

This is the layout:

```
<div class="main" id="main">
    <div class="container">...</div> <!--some container-->
    <div class="container"> <!--one of the many cards-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card d-flex flex-column">
                    <div class="expand visible">
                        <a href="#" class="text-primary float-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_149" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse_149"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body bg-white">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">...</div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 pt-1">...</div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 pt-1">...</div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 pt-1">...</div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="row pt-2">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="collapse" id="collapse_149">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-12 pt-2">...</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">...</div> <!-- navigation container --> 
</div>
```

JS:

```
$.post(
    'path',
    {
        params
    },
    function (result) {
        $('#main').html(result);
    }
);
```

The result is everything that you see in the `main` class.

I could fix that issue with this: `$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 1)`. But that's avoiding, not solving, the problem.

I'm not even sure what is causing the issue. Is it Chrome, Bootstrap 4 Collapse or the asynchronous ajax call? I assume after updating the content in `main`, somehow in Chrome the position on the screen gets 'fixed' to the bottom of the page.

I would like to understand what's causing the issue and solve it accordingly.

Maybe worth mentioning. The total height of the cards on page 1 is greater than on page 2. This is due to some cards having extra info. Maybe Chrome is calculating the initial window height and then it doesn't recalculate the height on page 2, instead it does only after scrolling a bit.

Comment: You say it only happens in Chrome. Have you tried a hard refresh? (`Ctrl+F5`)
And why is the class `container` defined three times in HTML? Is this necessary?This might collide with the CSS because you got one for holding the cards and one for navigation.

Comment: @Sanguinary Could you elaborate what I should be expecting after hard refreshing? It kinda defies the purpose of loading the content dynamically, otherwise I wouldn't be using ajax. 
Thank you for pointing out the multiple use of containers, I removed them. The problem still persists.

Comment: A hard refresh would remove cache that Chrome stores. This is not always a problem. I obviously do not expect you to hard refresh everytime.
Use the developer console (`CTRL+SHIFT+I`) to check for possible CSS overlaps like `overflow` and `height` issues. I still believe this is an issue with CSS or DOM and not your JS.

Comment: I figured out what is causing this behavior, it's the `overflow-anchor` property: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll/issues/138. Will probably use the fix described in the OP, by checking if at bottom and then subtracting 1.